# WiX / Windows Installer: install sequence documentation

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer

not sure if this is the appropriate forum for this question, but here goes:

i am building an installer using the WiX Toolset 3.14 and i'm having trouble understanding the installation sequence.  i understand that WiX is supposed to be more declarative, but in my project things seem to be happening in a strange sequence compared to most other installers.

Behavior:
user launches installation, my path alteration dialog is the first dialog presented in the sequence.  however, the UAC window doesn't pop up until after the user accepts the installation path.  is this normal?  seems like for most installations, that UAC window pops up as soon as the installation is launched.

so my thinking is that i am not quite understanding the installation sequence concept in Windows Installer.

Question:

1) does this have to do with my `<Show>` tags `Before=""` or `After=""` attributes?

2) **the documentation for WiX does not provide links to documentation about the legal values for these two attributes.  where can i find that documentation?**

there isn't much point posting code in this situation, but this is the installation sequence.  i'm not sure what the relevant code to post would be other than this.  if there's anything else i should post, please comment and i will add any code needed to this original post.  thanks!

```
  <!-- sequence of dialogs to show when running in admin mode. -->
  <AdminUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="CustomDlg" After="CostFinalize"/>
    <Show Dialog="ExitDialog" OnExit="success"/>
    <Show Dialog="FatalError" OnExit="error"/>
    <Show Dialog="UserExit" OnExit="cancel"/>
    <Show Dialog="FilesInUse" OnExit="suspend"/>
  </AdminUISequence>

  <!-- sequence of dialogs to show when running in installation mode. -->
  <InstallUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="CustomDlg" After="CostFinalize"/>
    <Show Dialog="ExitDialog" OnExit="success"/>
    <Show Dialog="FatalError" OnExit="error"/>
    <Show Dialog="UserExit" OnExit="cancel"/>
    <Show Dialog="FilesInUse" OnExit="suspend"/>
  </InstallUISequence>
```

Answer (score 4):

MSI doesn't prompt for elevation until it needs the privileges. That's only when it's going to modify the machine, not when it's showing UI.